# How to reshape a matrix so that it reads columns first in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a Matrix

1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1

The output result is

1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1

How can I reshape this matrix so that it reads the columns first. I want the output like

1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

Thank You

Comment: Use the `'` operator, then read the documentation.

Comment: Read about `linear indexing` and how elements are stored in arrays for MATLAB.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, ... or `.'` =)

Comment: @RobertP. What is this operator `.'=)-` of which you write ? :-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark it's the "transpose and be happy" operator. On a serious note (to OP) type `help .'` in the command window in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

Reshape:

```
b = reshape(A.',1,[])
b =
     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
```

Transpose then create a vector:

```
c = A.';
d = c(:).'
d =
     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
```

Indexing:

```
e = A([1:size(e,1):end, 2:size(e,1):end])
e =
     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
```

You can of course use permute to transpose it, instead of `.'`:

```
f = permute(A,[2 1 3]);
g = f(:).'
g =
     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
```